# Getting a type error on my Backbone file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

so I will include the error along with my main.js file, if anyone can tell me what it is refering to? I think it is the templates but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Main.js file:

```
(function(){

    //app can be the name of the project/app
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Routes: {}

    };
    window.template = function (id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    };

    //Can get rid of the Collection and views out of the names of each
    //User Model
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'J.R.',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            email: 'jsmith@knicks.com',
            phone: '212-424-6234',
            birthday: '03/05/1982',
            city: 'New York'

        },


        location: function(){
            return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName') + 'is currently in ' + this.get('city') + '.';
        },

        validate: function(attrs) {
            if(!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real name.';
            }
            if(!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real name.';
            }
            if(attrs.email.length < 5 ) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if(attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if(attrs.city.length < 2 ) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.on('invalid', function(model, error){
            console.log(error);
            //when setting a user user.set('age', -55, {validate : true}); the validate true makes sure it validates
            });
        }

    });

    // list of users

    App.Collections.UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.User

    });

    //User View
    App.Views.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click .edit': 'edit'
    },

    edit: function() {

    },

    template: template('userTemplate'),

    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Render");
        this.render();

    },

    render: function() {
        var template = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
        //always return this on render methods
    }

    }); 

    // view for users
    App.Views.UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function() {

        },

        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(function(user) {
                //user is the model associated to the new created user
                var userView = new App.Views.UserView({model: user});
                this.$el.append(userView.el);
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });



    /*var user = new App.Collections.UsersCollection(  );
    var usersView = new App.Views.UsersView( users );

    $( document.body ).append( usersView.render().el );
    */
})();
```

This is the jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    script(src='/js/main.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(id='userTemplate', type='text/template')
        <%=firstName%>
        button.edit Edit
        <%=lastName%>
        button.edit Edit
        <%=email%>
        button.edit Edit
        <%=phone%>
        button.edit Edit
        <%=birthday%>
        button.edit Edit
        <%=city%>
        button.edit Edit
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is running *before* the browser sees your template `<script>` so `$('#userTemplate')` doesn't find anything so `$('#userTemplate').html()` isn't returning anything useful. Adding a `$(document).ready(...)` in the appropriate place should sort you out.

Comment: Should I put the javascript file at the end? the main.js one?

Comment: I prefer using `$(document).ready` so that I don't have to worry about load order as much.

Comment: Where in the file should I be adding that?

Comment: In your case, I'd probably wrap the `new App.Views.UsersView( users )` and related code in a document-ready handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are passing the JSON model to the template function.

Have you tried amending the code as follows:

**Global templating function**

```
window.template = function (id, model) {
    return _.template($('#' + id).html(), model);
};
```

**In your UserView**

```
template: function() {
    template('userTemplate', this.model.toJSON());
}

render: function() {
    var template = this.template();
    this.$el.html(template);
    return this;
    //always return this on render methods
}
```

Comment: Ok that has worked, how do I populate the page with the default values? Right now nothing shows up in the body?

Comment: I am not sure what your are doing to set up everything. Can you show me how you are instantiating your models, collections and views? BTW, if my answer helped, please feel free to upvote it :)

Comment: I am calling the script on my index page, and have all that code on that script file (main.js) that is all. Am i suppose to do something else to?

Comment: I am calling the script on my index page, and have all that code on that script file (main.js) that is all. Am i suppose to do something else to? Also, I am dropping console.log('test'); by the template function and other functions underneath it and none of them are showing except for the first one that is right inside the top function... Is the rest of the code being ignored because I am not getting any errors though?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the above code I can't see any instantiation of any models or collections, so from what you've shown me, there is nothing to render. I'd need to see the root el you are creating your views with and the instantiation of all of the components to help further. You could make a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, you are right I am actually not calling anything at all. I guess I will have to create new variables for a new model and run it all. I am going to come back to it thanks tho!